# Using split to get particular words in python

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a text file like the one given below.

```
EVENTS 16623232889 {"log": "Hello I am someone", "stream": "a", "cluster-name": "432"} 3232
EVENTS 16623232890 {"log": "I am doing something.", "stream": "b", "cluster-name": "432"} 2321
EVENTS 16623232891 {"log": "bbye", "stream": "c", "cluster-name": "432"} 231231
EVENTS 16623232892 {"log": "bbyee", "stream": "d", "cluster-name": "432"} 23123212
```

I want to just get the words which are present in the log. For example the output should be `Hello I am someone I am doing something. bbye bbyee`

I do know that I can remove the event and event number using the code given below but not sure how to go ahead with it now

```
file_name = "a.json"
with open(file_name) as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    lines[i] = line.split(" ", 2)[2]
lines = str(lines)
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    lines[i] = line.split(" ", 2)[2]
lines = str(lines)
```

Comment: It would be better to parse each line as a json after removing the event and event number and simply access it through `json["log"]`

Answer (score 2):

You can parse each line as a json/dictionary after removing Event and Event Number.

```
import json
file_name = "a.json"
with open(file_name) as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()
    # Removing Event and Event Number, then parsing line as a json
    lines = [json.loads(" ".join(line.split(" ")[2:])) for line in lines]
    print ([line["log"] for line in lines])
```

Output:

> ['Hello I am someone', 'I am doing something.', 'bbye', 'bbyee']

**EDIT:**
Removing the last field, along with the first two

```
import json
file_name = "a.json"
with open(file_name) as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()
    # Removing Event, Event Number and the Number at the end, then parsing line as a json
    lines = [json.loads(" ".join(line.split(" ")[2:-1])) for line in lines]
    print ([line["log"] for line in lines])
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit about how this code works cause it works with the above one, but if there are much more fields it is giving a JSONDecode error

Comment: The code basically extracts (for each line) everything after the second space and parses it into a python dictionary. Then it extracts only `log` from each dictionary. I can better answer if you can send one line from your other file in which there are more fields.

Comment: Oh okay I am sorry I got what the problem was there is a number at the end of each event. I have edited the question

Comment: See the edit, removed the last field by changing `[json.loads(" ".join(line.split(" ")[2:])) for line in lines]` to `[json.loads(" ".join(line.split(" ")[2:-1])) for line in lines]`

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate over the lines
2. split each line with `maxsplit` of two so that you get the list (in string).
3. give that to `json.loads` in order to get dictionary back.
4. get the `"log"` key from it.
5. join them together with `" ".join`

```py
from json import loads

text = """\
EVENTS 16623232889 {"log": "Hello I am someone", "stream": "a", "cluster-name": "432"}
EVENTS 16623232890 {"log": "I am doing something.", "stream": "b", "cluster-name": "432"}
EVENTS 16623232891 {"log": "bbye", "stream": "c", "cluster-name": "432"}
EVENTS 16623232892 {"log": "bbyee", "stream": "d", "cluster-name": "432"}
"""

print(" ".join(loads(line.split(maxsplit=2)[2])["log"] for line in text.splitlines()))
```

### After edit:

There are couple of ways you can do, I chose to go with regex:

```py
import re

text = """\
EVENTS 16623232889 {"log": "Hello I am someone", "stream": "a", "cluster-name": "432"} 3232
EVENTS 16623232890 {"log": "I am doing something.", "stream": "b", "cluster-name": "432"} 2321
EVENTS 16623232891 {"log": "bbye", "stream": "c", "cluster-name": "432"} 231231
EVENTS 16623232892 {"log": "bbyee", "stream": "d", "cluster-name": "432"} 23123212
"""

pattern = r'"log": *"(.*?)"'

print(" ".join(re.search(pattern, line).group(1) for line in text.splitlines()))
```

output:

```
Hello I am someone I am doing something. bbye bbyee
```

`"log": "(.*?)"` pattern searches for the content of the `"log"` key directly. I captured the content in a *group* so that I can retrieve it later with `group(1)`. Note that pattern should be non-greedy so that it stops after finding the first `"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works too, but can you see the edited question and explain how I can proceed with it

Comment: @GAURAVSHARMA do you have only one dictionary in a line?

Comment: Actually that is the output I am getting after running a command. So my aim is to read the file and just print out the logs onto another file

Comment: @GAURAVSHARMA see the update.

Comment: @GAURAVSHARMA open your file with `with open(...) as f:` then use: `print(" ".join(re.search(pattern, line).group(1) for line in f))`